# Not able to scrape text from a website using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to get the values for the fields as shown in the attached picture. This is my sample code and it's not fetching the required fields any corrections are welcomed.

```
span_xpath = "//div[@id='se-siteDetailsPanel-panel']"
name_xpath = "//div[@id='se-siteDetailsPanel-name']" + span_xpath
site_data.append(browser.find_element_by_xpath(name_xpath).text)

# address:
adrs1_xpath = "//div[@id='se-siteDetailsPanel-firstAddress']" + span_xpath
adrs2_xpath = "//div[@id='se-siteDetailsPanel-address']" + span_xpath
address = browser.find_element_by_xpath(adrs1_xpath).text + \
          browser.find_element_by_xpath(adrs2_xpath).text
site_data.append(address)

# installed: 
installed_xpath = "//div[@id='se-siteDetailsPanel-installationDate']" + span_xpath
site_data.append(browser.find_element_by_xpath(installed_xpath).text)

#updated
updated_xpath = "//div[@id='se-siteDetailsPanel-lastUpdateTime']" + span_xpath
site_data.append(browser.find_element_by_xpath(updated_xpath).text)

# peak:
peak_xpath = "//div[@id='se-siteDetailsPanel-peakPower']" + span_xpath
peak = browser.find_element_by_xpath(peak_xpath).text
site_data.append(peak.split()[0])
```

[image: Website Needed to be scrapped]

Comment: it can help if you will share the url

Comment: @bladerman can you see the picture that i have attached its inspect element shows all the fields

Comment: At line 3, when you inspect element by xpath "name_xpath" in your browser, is it returning any element?

Comment: @itronic1990... your hint worked actually i saw that the xspan was wrong i corrected the span path and it started fetching the values

Comment: @gmm005 awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `xpath` or `By_id`

If you cannot find the XPath then try chropath extension in chrome, you will easily find the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

@itronic1990... your hint worked actually i saw that the xspan was wrong i corrected the span path and it started fetching the values –